# Is it consistent relative to ZF that $\frak c = \aleph_\omega$?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, lo.logic

In ZFC we know that the continuum cannot have cofinality $\omega$.

However, in the Feferman-Levy model we have that $\frak c=\aleph_1$, and that $\operatorname{cf}(\omega_1)=\omega$. In fact in the Feferman-Levy model, $\aleph_\omega^L=\aleph_1^V$.

Is it consistent with ZF that $\frak c=\aleph_\omega$? Does that mean that the only restriction in ZF on the cardinality of the continuum is $\aleph_0<\frak c$?

Comment: Asaf, I think you are mistaken. Here is a proof in ZF that if ${\mathbb R}$ is a countable union of countable sets (as in the Feferman-Levy model) then every well-orderable subset of ${\mathbb R}$ is countable: If $\omega_1$ injects into ${\mathbb R}$, then so does the set ${\omega_1}^\omega$, because $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$. But then, by Schröder-Bernstein, ${\omega_1}^\omega$ has the same size as ${\mathbb R}$. (Cont.) 

Comment: (II). Now, here is the nice bit, essentially following the argument for König's lemma: If $X$ is a countable union of countable sets, then no map from $X$ to $\omega_1^\omega$ is onto. For if $f$ is a map and $X=\bigcup_n X_n$ with each $X_n$ countable, then each $f[X_n]$ is countable, so $T_n=\omega_1\setminus\{f(x)(n)\mid x\in X_n\}$ is non-empty. Let $\Phi:\omega\to\omega_1$ be the map that at $n$ picks the minimum of $T_n$. Then $\Phi$ is not in the range of $f$.

Comment: The fact that $\omega_1$ doesn't embed into $\mathbb{R}$ in the Feferman-Levy model is apparently due to Cohen - http://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/res/two-pt.pdf

Comment: @Andres: Thanks a lot, as I wrote to Joel in a comment, it seems that this was a dream that convinced me that in the Feferman-Levy $2^\omega=\omega_1$, as I can't find that reference anywhere. @Francois: Thanks for the reference, it seems interesting and I'll give it a read.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is no. The continuum cannot be $\aleph_\omega$, and this can be proved in ZF, that is, without using the axiom of choice. To see
this, suppose towards contradiction that $P(\omega)$ is equinumerous with
$\aleph_\omega$. Since $P(\omega)$ is equinumerous
with $P(\omega)^\omega$, and this does not require AC, it follows
that there is a bijection $f:\aleph_\omega\cong
(\aleph_\omega)^\omega$. Let $g(n)$ be the first ordinal
$\alpha\lt\aleph_\omega$ that is not among $f(\beta)(n)$
for any $\beta\lt\aleph_n$. Since there are fewer than
$\aleph_\omega$ many such $\beta$, it follows that there
are fewer than $\aleph_\omega$ many such $f(\beta)(n)$, and
so such an $\alpha$ exists. Thus, $g:\omega\to
\aleph_\omega$. But notice that for any particular
$\alpha\lt\aleph_\omega$, we have $\alpha\lt\aleph_n$ for
some $n$ and consequently $g(n)\neq f(\alpha)(n)$, and thus
$g\neq f(\alpha)$. Thus, $f$ was not surjective to
$(\aleph_\omega)^\omega$ after all, a contradiction.

This is just a standard proof of Konig's theorem (that
$\aleph_\omega^\omega\gt\aleph_\omega$), and the point is
that it doesn't use AC.

Comment: This argument is essentially the same as the argument that Andres gave in the comments above, but it seems to answer the whole question, and not just the issue about the reals being a countable union of countable sets. The proof shows more generally that the continuum, if well-orderable, cannot have countable cofinality, even in ZF. 

Comment: Thanks a lot, Joel. I swear I read somewhere that in the Feferman-Levy model $2^\omega=\omega_1$. I can't find it, and the proofs you and Andres gave convince me that it was probably in a dream.

Comment: Just for the record, the standard proof of the more general Konig's theorem ($\kappa^{cof(\kappa)}>\kappa$ for $\kappa$ any aleph) doesn´t use AC (it is essentially the same proof that Joel already gave).