# Can GCH fail everywhere every way?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, continuum-hypothesis

The following question is about if it is compatible to add to $\sf ZF$ an axiom asserting the existence of a countable transitive model of $\sf ZF$ such that for every strictly increasing function $f$ on the ordinals, we have a transitive countable model of $\sf ZF $ satisfying: $$\forall\alpha>0:\beth_\alpha = \aleph_{f(\alpha)}$$

Formally:

$  \exists M: M \equiv  \operatorname {CTM}(\mathsf {ZF}) \land \forall f \subseteq M \ \big{(}\\f: \operatorname {Ord}^M \to \operatorname {Ord}^M \land  \forall \alpha \forall \beta \, ( \beta > \alpha \to f(\beta) > f(\alpha) ) \\ \implies \\ \exists N : N \equiv  \operatorname {CTM}(\mathsf {ZF}) \land \operatorname {Ord}^N =\operatorname {Ord}^M \land (N \models \forall \alpha > 0 : \beth_\alpha=\aleph_{f(\alpha)})\big{)} $

Where "$\equiv\operatorname {CTM}(\mathsf {ZF})$" means "*is a countable transitive model of ZF*"

So this is to say that the generalized continuum hypothesis can fail everywhere and in everyway.

Comment: does ZF prove the cofinality restriction without choice? [I think so, but too many years have passed ...]

Comment: The fact that for each ordinal $\alpha$, $\beth_\alpha$ is well defined as a well-ordered cardinal number, is by itself equivalent to AC. Thus, $N$ is really a model of ZFC.

Comment: Ah I see thanks.

Comment: My point (see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78627/is-it-consistent-relative-to-zf-that-frak-c-aleph-omega ) is that also any other formalizaition of "fail everywhere in every way" is killed since restrictions do exist.

Comment: @NameNo, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No.  An early nontrivial constraint on the $\beth$ function comes from Kőnig's Theorem, that for all infinite $\kappa$, $\mathrm{cf}(2^\kappa)>\kappa$.  This implies that we cannot have $\beth_\alpha = \aleph_{f(\alpha)}$ for all $\alpha$, when $f(1) = \omega$, nor when $f(\omega+1)$ is a cardinal below $\aleph_\omega$.

Another constraint is Silver's Theorem, that if GCH holds below a singular of uncountable cofinality, then it holds at that singular as well.

Other constraints come from Shelah's PCF theory.  Shelah showed that if $\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit, then $2^{\aleph_\omega} < \aleph_{\omega_4}$.

Comment: +1. To the OP, it's worth explicitly saying that, per Easton's theorem, Konig's theorem is the only real restriction on the behavior of the continuum function ... on *regular* cardinals; as Silver's theorem and PCF theory show, the situation on *singular* cardinals is much more intricate.

Answer (score 12):

When working in ZF, one can have more freedom. See
[An Easton-like Theorem for Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory with the Axiom of Dependent Choice](https://arxiv.org/abs/1812.00960) and [An Easton-like theorem for Zermelo-Fraenkel Set Theory without Choice](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.00205).