# Is existence of a cardinal that witness non-failure of GCH everywhere everyway, a theorem of ZF?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, continuum-hypothesis, cardinal-characteristics

In an earlier [positing](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413804/can-gch-fail-everywhere-every-way) to $\mathcal MO$, it appears that the answer to if the $\sf GCH$ can fail everywhere in *every way* is to the negative, this is the case in $\sf ZFC$, however it also appears that matters are more free in absence of $\sf AC$. So, here the quenstion is if the opposite direction in provable in $\sf ZF$.

The following question is about if it is true in $\sf ZF$ that for every stage $V_\alpha$ of the cumulative hierarchy there is a cardinal $\kappa > |V_\alpha|$ such that the cardinality of $V_{\alpha+1} \neq \kappa$ in all models of $\sf ZF$?

Formally, this is:

$ \forall M: (M \models \mathsf {ZF}) \implies \\\forall \alpha \in M \, \exists \kappa \in M \big{(} (M \models |V_\alpha| < \kappa) \land \forall N: N \approx M \to N \models|V_{\alpha+1}| \neq \kappa \big{)}$

Where "||" refers to cardinality defined after Scott; $N \approx M$ means that $N$ is a model of $\sf ZF$ that shares the same ordinals and cardinals with $M$, i.e., $\operatorname {Ord}^M = \operatorname {Ord}^N$ and $\operatorname {Card}^M = \operatorname {Card}^N$

In the case of $\sf ZFC$, this seems to be the case, well at least for regular $\alpha$, and the singlular seems to be even more restricted. But, is this the case in $\sf ZF$?

Comment: I don't understand your question. It's also very *very*, **very**, ***very***, ***VERY*** hard to control the cardinal structure of models of ZF. We have little to no idea what happens there. So to say that M and N have the same cardinals, in the Scott sense, is kind of a big blowout here. And it's even worse since it's not clear that $V_{\alpha+1}^M$ has the same cardinality as it had before, etc. My point is that there is too much going on in this question which lies in uncharted, and frankly incomprehensible (with the current technology) territories.

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly $\operatorname {Card}^M = \operatorname {Card}^N$ means? Probably the literal sense, since every element of $M$ is contained in some Scott cardinal, so that equality could only hold if $M=N$.

Comment: I meant "probably *not* the literal sense, since..."

Comment: @Wojowu, I agree with you, there are problems in the cardinal structure. I'll see into that.

Comment: @Wojowu: The way I understand that is that any two sets which are in $M\cap N$, they have the same cardinality in $N$ if and only if they have the same cardinality in $M$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a somewhat trivial answer.

Note that $V_\alpha$, for an infinite $\alpha$, have a particularly nice set of properties which follow from the fact that $|V_\alpha\times V_\alpha|=|V_\alpha|$.

Now, easily, if $\sf AC$ fails, we can find arbitrarily high such cardinals. Simply take $|V_\alpha|+\aleph(V_\alpha)$, where $\aleph(x)$ is the Hartogs number of $x$. By Tarski's lemma, this cardinal is not idemmultiple.

If $\sf AC$ holds, then refer to the previous question you've asked.

Comment: But if $\sf GCH$ holds in $N$, then clearly $|V_{\alpha+1}|= |\aleph(V_\alpha)|$

Comment: You cannot move from non-GCH to a GCH model without changing the cardinal structure. Not to mention if you're adding GCH, you're adding AC back into your universe.

Comment: why $|V_{\alpha+1}| \neq |V_\alpha|+ \aleph(V_\alpha)$ if $V_\alpha$ is not well orderable?

Comment: Because the LHS satisfies $x^2=x$ and the RHS doesn't.

Comment: But $|V_{\alpha+1}|^2 = |V_{\alpha+1}|$ might with $~\neg \sf AC$!?

Comment: No, that is a theorem of ZF, no choice needed. For any infinite $\alpha$, $V_\alpha$ is equipotent with its square.

Comment: For limit ordinals, this is trivial, since $V_\alpha\times V_\alpha\subseteq V_\alpha$. Now, by induction, $$V_{\alpha+1}=2^{V_\alpha}=2^{V_\alpha\times V_\alpha}=2^{V_\alpha+V_\alpha}=2^{V_\alpha}\times2^{V_\alpha}=V_{\alpha+1}\times V_{\alpha+1}.$$

Comment: I think there is an error in this question, the structure of the Scott's cardinals is not that flexible as I thought. I need to look into it. Thanks for this answer.