# Can GCH fail everywhere in every finite way?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, continuum-hypothesis

Since the $\sf GCH$ cannot fail everywhere everyway (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/413804/can-gch-fail-everywhere-every-way)), the question here is if it can fail everywhere in every finite manner, that if we have a strictly increasing function $f$ on the ordinals at finite   intervals $\geq 2 $, then we can have: $$\forall\alpha: 2^{\aleph_\alpha}= \aleph_{f(\alpha)}$$

Formally:

$$  \exists M: M \equiv  \operatorname {CTM}(\mathsf {ZF}) \land \forall f \subseteq M \ \big{(}\\f: \operatorname {Ord}^M \to \operatorname {Ord}^M \land  \forall \alpha \forall \beta \, ( \beta > \alpha \to f(\beta) > f(\alpha) ) \\ \land \forall \alpha \exists n \in \mathbb N_2 \, (f(\alpha)=\alpha+n) \\ \implies \\ \exists N : N \equiv  \operatorname {CTM}(\mathsf {ZF}) \land \operatorname {Ord}^N =\operatorname {Ord}^M \\ \land (N \models \forall \alpha: 2^{\aleph_\alpha}= \aleph_{f(\alpha)})\big{)} $$

where "$\equiv\operatorname {CTM}(\mathsf {ZF})$" means "*is a countable transitive model of ZF*"; $\mathbb N_2= \mathbb N \setminus \{0,1\}$.

> Is this possible in $\sf ZFC$?

${}$

Comment: The way you wrote it? No. The $\beth$ function is continuous, but $f$ is not required to be continuous in any shape or form. If you add that $f$ is continuous, then this is a fairly straightforward application of Easton's theorem, since it really means that we start with GCH and change the continuum function only on successor cardinals, by increasing it only by a finite number of successors, too.

Comment: Why $\beth_\alpha$ rather than $2^{\aleph_\alpha}$? It would seem it is the latter that you are interested in. In particular, this function is not necessarily continuous.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo, Agreed! Thanks

Comment: @AsafKaragila, Thanks for noting the continuity issue. But I'm not sure of the rest of your comment. Easton 's theorem is only concerned with regular cardinals, so it doesn't mention anything about the cardinality of singulars violating GCH, but here with this axiom you have GCH breached everywhere including the singulars. It says that those also can be breached by any finite interval. I mean even if I add "$f$ is continuous", still Easton's theorem doesn't seem to touch it?

Comment: Zuhair, if the function is continuous, then its values at limit stages are determined by the values before them. Hence, there is nothing you can do at limit stages.

Comment: This is answered by Silver's Theorem: If GCH holds below a singular of uncountable cofinality, then it holds at that singular as well.  So we cannot have $f(\alpha) = \alpha+1$ for all $\alpha<\omega_1$ and $f(\omega_1) = \omega_1+2$.  Since this is already contained in my answer to the previous question, I will just leave this as a comment.

Comment: @MonroeEskew, Oops, I see, this happened when I changed matters to $2^\kappa$, anyhow the question is about global failure of the GCH, so differences by $1$ are not on the table. I've edited the question, the finite differences must always be greater than 1.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, are you saying that for $f$ to meet being "continuous", then at every limit stage the difference must be set to $0$ thus agreeing with Easton's. The problem is that this is not on the table with the formulation using $\beth$ symbols because the naturals belong to $\mathbb N^+$, so the continuum is not alwayed to succeed at any stage. So this constitutes a difference from Easton's theorem. The formulation (previous one using the $\beth$s), freely allows any finite difference at limit stages and accepts all those functions, I don't think this is an application of Easton's theorem.